# Using CherryPy with Routes dispatching

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy

I'm trying to switch a CherryPy application from standard CherryPy dispatching to RoutesDispatcher.

The following python code routes `/`correctly using standard CherryPy dispatching.  My goal is to convert this same code to run using RoutesDispatcher.  I've flailed around with snippets I've found but have not been able to find a complete example of a CherryPy application using Routes.

```
class ABRoot:  

    def index(self):
        funds = database.FundList()
        template = lookup.get_template("index.html")
        return template.render(fund_list=funds)

index.exposed = True 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(ABRoot(), '/', 'ab.config')
```

I have flailed around trying to combine code from various partial tutorials that I've found without any luck.

What changes do I have to make to `__main__` to load and route via `RoutesDispatcher`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code that I eventually got working.  Changes I needed to make that were not immediately obvious to me:

1. I had to move my configuration from a file to a dictionary so that I could add the dispatcher to it.
2. I had to include a call to cherrypy.mount before cherrypy.quickstart.
3. I had to include `dispatcher.explicit = False`

I hope anyone else dealing with this issue finds this answer helpful.

```
class ABRoot:  

     def index(self):
         funds = database.FundList()
         template = lookup.get_template("index.html")
         return template.render(fund_list=funds)

if __name__ == '__main__':


     dispatcher = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
     dispatcher.explicit = False
     dispatcher.connect('test', '/', ABRoot().index)

     conf = {
    '/' : {
        'request.dispatch' : dispatcher,
        'tools.staticdir.root' : "C:/Path/To/Application",
        'log.screen' : True
    },
    '/css' : {
        'tools.staticdir.debug' : True,
        'tools.staticdir.on' : True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir' : "css"
    },
    '/js' : {
        'tools.staticdir.debug' : True,
        'tools.staticdir.on' : True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir' : "js"
    }
     }

     #conf = {'/' : {'request.dispatch' : dispatcher}}

     cherrypy.tree.mount(None, "/", config=conf) 
     cherrypy.quickstart(None, config=conf)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "dispatcher.explicit = False" line?  In trying to solve an issue with upgrading to CherryPy 3.2, I have seen reference to this, however it was applied to the mapper "dispatcher.mapper.explicit = False".  The code above seems to work the same with and without the line.